# beforeCreate function implemention best practice

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, bcrypt, sails.js

Hi while I have implemented bcrypt beforeCreate function there are two ways people implemented that with a function signature

```
beforeCreate: function (user, next, cb)
```

or with a function signature

```
beforeCreate: function (user, cb)
```

and they call either cb() or next() after finishing the function, I am wondering which is the better way and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the Sails/Waterline lifecycle callbacks should have two parameters: `values` which is an object containing values of the record's fields and `cb` which is a callback to be called once everything is done. So, the right signature would be:

```
beforeCreate: function (values, cb) { ... }
```

See [Waterline readme](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/4881027937b444671a8e3b6aea8d307a5e0183b4/README.md#lifecycle-callbacks) for all lifecycle callback signatures.

Comment: `next` and `cb` are the same thing in this case, just two different naming conventions for the callback. Either way like @bredikhin said the `values` is the data being submitted to the model. I do this with bcrypt password hashing and you can see that example [here](https://github.com/RelativeMedia/sails-PassportLocalMongoExample/blob/master/api/models/User.js#L30-L42)

Comment: Thanks bredikhin for your answer,  and big thanks to gorelative for your comment and providing the example. :)